# Как найти дубликаты в большом csv файле?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Как найти дубликаты в большом csv файле, который не помещается в ОЗУ? Интересуют способы без разделения файла на части.
В моем примере часть строки помещается в set и по условию совпадения дубликаты записываются в отдельный файл. Но в случае, если оперативы будет мало, программа вряд-ли будет работать.

```
import csv
import time
import sys


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    read_file  = 'input.csv'
    write_file = 'output.csv'
    rows = set()

    with open(read_file) as in_f, open(write_file, 'w', newline='') as out_f:
        reader, writer = csv.reader(in_f), csv.writer(out_f)
        for row in reader:
            item = ''.join(row[7:14])
            if item not in rows:
                rows.add(item)
            else:
                writer.writerow(row)
        print(sys.getsizeof(rows))
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2 - t1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: А вы попробуйте. Может и хватит памяти. Если не хватит, то можно через `Dask` попробовать группировать данные, например. Но по нормальному возможно и правда проще всего будет записать в отдельные файлы совпадающие по `id` штуки, а потом их оттуда уже собрать.

Comment: Думаю, что ответ на ваш вопрос находится в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file) теме

Comment: @tonysdev С дубликатами это не поможет, там просто про чтение же

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, если бы был пример файла, тогда бы еще и дал ответ на его вопрос, а так пока что есть совет работы с большим файлом

Comment: @tonysdev Тут в коде файл и так читается построчно, с этим то нет проблем.